# Google Map GMSPolygon is not updating in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have added a GMSPolygon in GMSMapView and when i click on button to update my latitude and longitude for polygon then its not updating at all. I can see only old polygon.

This is my code for taking coordinates from NSArray and displaying a polygon, its working perfectly.

```
-(void)loadAreasInMap{

    for(NSArray *polygon in [[vehicle model] area]){
        self.path = [GMSMutablePath path];

                for(int i = 0; i < [[polygon  valueForKey:@"polygon_coordinates"] count]; i++){

                    [self.path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[[polygon  valueForKey:@"polygon_coordinates"] objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue],[[[[polygon  valueForKey:@"polygon_coordinates"] objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] floatValue])];
                }

                GMSPolygon *rectangle = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:self.path];
                rectangle.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.4];
                rectangle.map = self.mapView;

    }

    [self.mapView bringSubviewToFront:self.locationMarkerView];
    CLLocation *userLocation = [[locManager sharedManager] userLocation];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:userLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:userLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                 zoom:7];
    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];



}
```

now when i click on button i will call this method to update my coordinates and re draw the polygon, but i can see all logs which saying method working correctly but map is not updating.

```
 -(void)buttonClicked{

   [self.mapView clear];
   [self.loadAreasInMap];
 }
```

Please tell me how can i update map

Answer (score 0):

What if you define your polygon as an instance variable, load it with a dummy path and set the .map property to nil. Then when you click the button, load the polygon with the new path and set the map property to the map view.

```
GMSPolygon *rectangle;
```

Somewhere in your init fill it with a dummy Path:

```
    GMSMutablePath *path = [[GMSMutablePath alloc] init];
    [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0,0.0)];
    [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.1,0.0)];
    [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0,0.1)];

    rectangle = [GMSPolygon  polygonWithPath:path];
    rectangle.map = nil;
```

Then in your function, load the new Path and set  `rectangle.map = mapView;`

You don't have to clear the whole map for it.